# Is it possible to use an animated texture to control smoke?

Tags: animation, texturing, image, smoke-simulation

I am attempting to use an image sequence to control which parts of my mesh emit smoke over the course of an animation.

I have set an image sequence to a texture in the Texture Panel, and pointed it at the image sequence I would like to use.  The image in the preview panel appears correct, though it only updates when playback is stopped, or when moving frame-by-frame.  Regardless, I then set this texture in the smoke flow object, under the Texture tab (mapping is set to UV).

Unfortunately, the texture does not appear to update over the course of the animation.  It occasionally updates when I change a setting in the smoke emitter.  The effect is that the smoke emitter appears to only use a single frame of the image sequence as a texture, and does not change each frame as I would like it to.

Is there a workaround to get this to work?